# Angular7 : Export data to CSV

Tags: angular, csv, angular7

I recently migrated my project from Angular 5 to Angular 7,while installing angular5-csv I get the following warning:

> npm WARN angular5-csv@0.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular5-csv@0.2.10 requires a peer of @angular/http@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular5-csv@0.2.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

package.json:

```
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
    .
    .
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.10"
```

Is there an alternate to angular5-csv that I should now be using?

Comment: What kind of data it will be JSON or something else?

Comment: .csv is very simple format, so some alternative is write your own function (static function) to make conversion from array of objects to csv  - even in stack overflow you can find such functions ready to use :)

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes it's JSON data (I have a d3 tree and need each nodes data in this file)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski true but I would like to use it as my last option:)

Comment: You can use the JS library [papaparse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) while waiting for [ngx-papaparse](https://github.com/alberthaff/ngx-papaparse) to become available for Angular 7. It's really easy to use.

Comment: @sah1 look - your approach bring problems to you when you wanna upgrade angular... so in future you can have similar problems because your are third-part dependent - consider that :P (of course it is case only for "small" libraries which can be rewrite inside project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

package.json:

```
"angular7-csv": "^0.2.12",
```

Example for Angular7:

```
import { AngularCsv } from 'angular7-csv';

var data = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    age: 13,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    age: 11,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 4',
    age: 10,
    average: 8.2,
    approved: true,
    description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
  },
];

new AngularCsv(data, 'My Report');
```

Comment: How to add extra sheets in this example please suggest.